# Cardinality of given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given,

$$A=\{B\subset \mathbb{N}: B \text{ is finite} \vee B^c \text{ is finite }\}$$

How can I prove that A is countable.

For me it seems it is uncountable.

Comment: The set $A_1=\{B\subset \mathbb{N}: B\text{ is finite}\}$ is countable as it is a countable union of subsets with maximum element $n$. Now show $A_2=\{B\subset \mathbb{N}: B^C\text{ is finite}\}$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \{B \subset \mathbb N | B \text{ finite}\} \cup \{B^C \subset \mathbb N | B \text{ is finite}\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{B \subset \mathbb N | |B| = n\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{B^C \subset \mathbb N | |B| = n \}$$
From this, the enumeration can be received by a diagonalisation.